# Cookies, domains, ports

Tags: java, javascript, cookies, firebug

I have two web sites, both of the websites under same domain.

1. https://www.fat.service.map.global.com:24536
2. https://fat.test.service.global.com

first URL - https://www.fat.service.map.global.com:24536 sets a cookie in the parent domain as, (`name=lang, value=en, domain=.global.com`).

Second URL - https://fat.test.service.global.com needs to access this same cookie. But the cookie is not visible (null) from the backend code of the second URL.

But when I checked the cookie within Firebug it shows me the value of the cookie with the domain value as `.global.com`(which is correct)

So why I cannot access the cookie within the backend of the second URL??

Can anyone shed some light on this...?

Comment: both urls are of deferment domains.

Comment: The browser will not allow you to see cookies from diffrent URLs (Domains). 
If you require this functionallity consider using apache rewite rules to mask domains.

Comment: @niiraj874u both urls are having the same domain of ".global.com", isn't it?

Comment: no browser store it by URL

Comment: @niiraj874u So there is no effect on putting the domain attribute on the Cookie as ".global.com"

Comment: You should add the header that gets sent for setting the cookie. Firebug displays this within its [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about `.global.com` is correct, but there are more things to consider when setting a cookie. I.e. the cookie may be restricted to a specific port (when the cookie is set via a `Set-Cookie2` header, see [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965)) or path, for example.

I've tested your case using Apache + PHP on my local machine, and it worked fine for me.

My Apache configuration:

```
# Listen on different ports
Listen 80
Listen 24536

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:24536

<VirtualHost *:24536>
  DocumentRoot /path/to/my/document/root
  ServerName www.fat.service.map.global.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /path/to/my/document/root
  ServerName fat.test.service.global.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Created a PHP script 'test.php' in the document root containing this:

```
<?php
  // Output all cookies
  var_dump($_COOKIE);

  // Set the cookie when the host is 'www.fat.service.map.global.com'
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www.fat.service.map.global.com') !== false) {
    setcookie('lang', 'en', time() + 3600, '/', '.global.com');
  }
?>
```

This generates the following header for setting the cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: lang=en; expires=Sat, 27-Feb-2016 09:23:33 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=.global.com
```

and gave me the following output for both domains:
[image: Cookie available at www.fat.service.map.global.com]

[image: Cookie available at fat.test.service.global.com]

The only difference to your configuration is that I am not using HTTPS, i.e. I'm not using port 443 for the second virtual host. Though I believe that doesn't make any difference, as both of your domains are served via HTTPS.